# How to decode qr file's text in QRCoder C# library?

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-core, qr-code

I am using [QRCoder library](https://github.com/codebude/QRCoder) to create QR Codes for texts. The QR codes are correctly generated but I want to know how to decode text from the qr files.

My code is:

```
QRCodeGenerator qrGenerator = new QRCodeGenerator();
QRCodeData qrCodeData = qrGenerator.CreateQrCode("The text which should be encoded.", QRCodeGenerator.ECCLevel.Q);
qrCodeData.SaveRawData("my-raw-file.qrr", QRCodeData.Compression.Uncompressed);

QRCodeData qrCodeData1 = new QRCodeData("my-raw-file.qrr", QRCodeData.Compression.Uncompressed);
byte[] bData = qrCodeData1.GetRawData(QRCodeData.Compression.Uncompressed);
```

In the above code you can see I am creating the Qr file named `my-raw-file.qrr` using the `SaveRawData()` function:

```
qrCodeData.SaveRawData("my-raw-file.qrr", QRCodeData.Compression.Uncompressed);
```

The file gets created on the website's folder. Now I want to read the text from this .qrr file. This text is 'The text which should be encoded.'.

I read the file using the below given codes:

```
QRCodeData qrCodeData1 = new QRCodeData("my-raw-file.qrr", QRCodeData.Compression.Uncompressed);
byte[] bData = qrCodeData1.GetRawData(QRCodeData.Compression.Uncompressed);
```

You can see the below image which shows it?

[image]

I get the bytes array in the bData variable. I want to know how to get the text now?

Comment: Try reading the documentation next time: https://github.com/codebude/QRCoder/wiki#2-what-can-and-cant-qrcoder-do-for-you "QRCoder can generate QR Codes but it can't read them"

Comment: thank you @IanKemp.